# Directly embedding a base64 string into @font-face. Is my syntax incorrect?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to directly embed a font using `@font-face` just like examples I've seen. Visual Studio is flagging my `url(...)` function as having an unbalanced parantheses and is flagging a bunch of the base-64 characters as being unexpected. In addition, my page is not rendering the font. So I know something must be wrong.

**NOTE:** I shortened the base-64 string due to character limits on SO posts.

```
@font-face { font-family: 'CHNfnt_R'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: url(data:font/truetype;base64,
AAEAAAATAQAABAAwRkZUTV/PWxEAAAE8AAAAHEdERUYC8gHSAAABWAAAACxHUE9Tsxt/TQAAAYQA
AA3iR1NVQibDINUAAA9oAAAAYE9TLzK5Ivx/AAAPyAAAAGBjbWFwn9BCKgAAECgAAAHiY3Z0IBgY
EWAAABIMAAAAQmZwZ21TtC+nAAASUAAAAmVnYXNwAAAAEAAAFLgAAAAIZ2x5ZhleacIAABTAAACN
vGhlYWQDbZjlAACifAAAADZoaGVhDAQIEWyDzsCK7EDRnYrRLARIEWyEDUCK7EDRnYrRLASIEWyEWkCK7ED
RnYrRLATIEWyEjsCK7EDRnYrRLAUIEWyEzoCK7EDRnYrRLAVIEWyFDkCK7EDRnYrRLAWIEWyFTYC
K7EDRnYrRLAXIEWyFi4CK7EDRnYrRFmwFCsAAAFSe/aUAAA=) 
format('truetype');}
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper syntax is:

```
@font-face {
font-family:"font-name";
src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,[base-64 code here]);
    url('font.ttf') format('truetype');
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
}

@font-face {
font-family:"font-name";
src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,[base-64 code here]);
    url('font.ttf') format('truetype');
font-style:normal;
font-weight:600;
}

@font-face {
font-family:"font-name";
src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,[base-64 code here]);
    url('font.ttf') format('truetype');
font-style:normal;
font-weight:900;
}
```

Comment: Why did you post 3 examples, with the only difference being font-weight?

Comment: If you want to use a font that has separate font-files for separate weights.  Otherwise, 1 is fine.

Comment: The code you provided looks broken. Are you sure there should be a semicolon after the first url() definition in each of your @font-face definitions? To me it looks like it should be a comma. Even the syntax highlighter doesn't know what to do with it.